# Typo3: No columns definition in TCA table

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.7.x

since i updated Typo3 from 6.2 to 8.7.13 i get the following error:

## 1438594406: No columns definition in TCA table tx_cmagnews_domain_model_news (More information)

UnexpectedValueException thrown in file
/kunden/211624_70794/rp-hosting/5056114/6056114/typo3cms/typo3_src-8.7.13/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/FormDataProvider/InitializeProcessedTca.php in line 48.

I already replaced all $TCA with $GLOBALS['TCA'].

Does anyone have some other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

yes, the answer is that you have to delete everything in file ext_tables.php where 
tables are defined like $TCA['tx_yourextensionname_domain_model_xyz'] = array() e.g.
Since newer Typo versions, control of TCA is taken by the replacement files you put in the directory Configuration/TCA or Configuration/TCA/Overrides